# How to use HTML5 Router in Angular 2 Webpack instead of default Hash Provider

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing

When you run [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) on your machine. The default Routing is the Hash routing. How could I change it to HTML5 router.

Comment: I guess this will help you : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles.
EDIT : Be careful to check if your angular2 starter is RC5 or RC4

Answer (score 0):

Change `useHash` value in `app.module.ts` to `false`:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: false, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
```